# How to write Tensorflow KMeans Estimator script for Sagemaker

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, k-means, amazon-sagemaker

I'm attempting to use Tensorflows `tf.contrib.factorization.KMeansClustering` estimator with SageMaker but am having some trouble. The output of my SageMaker `predictor.predict()` call looks incorrect. The cluster values are too large as they should be integers from 0-7. (I have the number of clusters set to 8).

I get a similar output on every run (where the last half of the array is `4L` or some other digit like `0L`). There are 40 values in the array because that s how many rows(users and their ratings I pass into the `predict()` function)

Example:
`{'outputs': {u'output': {'int64_val': [6L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L], 'dtype': 9, 'tensor_shape': {'dim': [{'size': 100L}]}}}, 'model_spec': {'signature_name': u'serving_default', 'version': {'value': 1534392971L}, 'name': u'generic_model'}}`

The data I'm working with is a sparse matrix of item ratings where `rows=users`, `cols=items`, and the cells contain floats bewteen 0.0 and 10. So my input data is a matrix instead of the typical array of features.

I think the issue might be in the serving_input_fn function. Here is my SageMaker entry_point script:

```
def estimator_fn(run_config, params):
    #feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column('inputs', shape=list(params['input_shape']))]
    return tf.contrib.factorization.KMeansClustering(num_clusters=NUM_CLUSTERS,
                            distance_metric=tf.contrib.factorization.KMeansClustering.COSINE_DISTANCE,
                            use_mini_batch=False,
                            feature_columns=None,
                            config=run_config)

def serving_input_fn(params):
    tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None])
    return tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn({'inputs': tensor})()

def train_input_fn(training_dir, params):
    """ Returns input function that would feed the model during training """
    return generate_input_fn(training_dir, 'train.csv')


def eval_input_fn(training_dir, params):
    """ Returns input function that would feed the model during evaluation """
    return generate_input_fn(training_dir, 'test.csv')


def generate_input_fn(training_dir, training_filename):
    """ Generate all the input data needed to train and evaluate the model. """
    # Load train/test data from s3 bucket
    train = np.loadtxt(os.path.join(training_dir, training_filename), delimiter=",")
    return tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x={'inputs': np.array(train, dtype=np.float32)},
        y=None,
        num_epochs=1,
        shuffle=False)()
```

In `generate_input_fn()`, `train` is the numpy ratings matrix.

If it helps, here is my call to the `predict()` function, (`ratings_matrix` is a 40 x num_items numpy array):

```
mtx = tf.make_tensor_proto(values=ratings_matrix,
                           shape=list(ratings_matrix.shape), dtype=tf.float32)
result = predictor.predict(mtx)
```

I feel like the issue is something simple I'm missing. This is the first ML algorithm I've written so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks javadba for your answer!

I am not very well adversed in Machine Learning or TensorFlow, so please correct me. However, it looks like you were able to integrate with SageMaker, but the predictions aren't what you are expecting.

Ultimately, SageMaker runs your [EstimatorSpec](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/README.rst#preparing-the-tensorflow-training-script) with [train_and_evaluate](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-container/blob/master/src/tf_container/trainer.py#L73) for training and uses TensorFlow Serving for your predictions. It doesn't have any other hidden functionalities, so the results you get from your KMeans predictions using the TensorFlow estimator is going to be independent of SageMaker. It might be affected by how you define your serving_input_fn and output_fn however.

When you run this same estimator outside of the SageMaker ecosystem using the same setup, do you get predictions in the format you're expecting?

The SageMaker TensorFlow experience is open sourced here and shows what is possible and isn't as of now.
https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-container

Comment: Thanks! I I ran the KMeansClustering Estimator on it's own and found the bug. I was using a different number of input rows for the matrix I passed to `serving_input_fn` and the `predict()` functions.

I just needed to pass in the number of rows the serving function was expecting. I'm going to use ALS next and I should get more accurate predictions like @javadba suggested. I just wanted to get this working first.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem -and certainly the input dataset - appears to be more apt towards `Alternating Least Squares` / `Non-Negative Matrix Factorization`: these are properly directed towards providing recommendations given `user`/`item` matrices as inputs.

It appears that `Sagemaker` may not have this line of algorithms presently - but they do have `Factorization Machines https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/fact-machines.html - that are a similar approach for recommendation systems.

Here is a blog from Amazon on how to set it up: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/build-a-movie-recommender-with-factorization-machines-on-amazon-sagemaker/ :  some high points in it are :

The blog shows how to use  the `SageMaker` `Factorization Machines` with the `MovieLens` input dataset:  you can find an an analog that your `user` is their `user` and your `item` is their `movie`:

[image]

You will need to write the data to `protobuf` files as follows:

[image]

You will then invoke the `fit()` method on their API and can look at results including the `F1` score on the resulting output.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! It does make sense that this particular scenario is better suited for ALS and I actually had planned on applying that algorithm to this use case next. However, right now I'm just trying to create groupings of "similar" users based on their movie preference. Is this possible with the Tensorflow KMeansClustering estimator and SageMaker? Thanks!